# Cassandra won't replicate data to new DC

Tags: cassandra

I have a single-node Cassandra 3.11.4 setup in one datacenter.

I know that is awful, and wrong, so I am trying to fix it by moving the data to a 3-node setup in another datacenter.

Taking a snapshot and copying it over means too much downtime, so I am trying to add the 3 new nodes to the cluster and have Cassandra replicate the data over.

The strategy for my user keyspace, as well as `system_distributed`, `system_auth` and `system_traces` is this:
`{'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', '(newdc)': '3', '(olddc)': '1'}`

All nodes see each other properly (1 in the old datacenter, 3 in the new).
All nodes report UN.
All nodes report 100% effective ownership.
I can query my keyspace from any node and get data back.
There is a folder for my user keyspace in the data folder on the new nodes, but it is empty.
The new nodes show <1MB load, which seems a bit low compared to the 600GB+ from the original.

When I do `nodetool rebuild -- (olddc)` on any of the new nodes, it returns almost immediately without any message. That's the command everyone tells me is supposed to actually move the data, but no dice.

How do I get the data to actually replicate over?

In the log, I get `Some ranges in (...all my ranges...) are already available, skipping streaming these ranges`. Available yes, I'd actually like the node to have the data though!

`nodetool status` shows this:

```
Datacenter: (new)
==================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  XX.XXX.X.110  775.49 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
UN  XX.XXX.X.109  929.93 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
UN  XX.XXX.X.108  710.75 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
Datacenter: (old)
=============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  XXX.XX.X.233  676.17 GiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
```

Restarted the old node, and now `nodetool rebuild` gives me this:

```
nodetool: Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (-1652045364361720276,-1613609154633147610] in keyspace system_distributed
```

Restarted all nodes again, and things seem to be working now.

Part of it seems to be because the original "cluster" only has one node. *DO NOT DO THIS*, they aren't kidding when they say things go bad when you do. It's not just redundancy, things flat-out don't work right.

Second part seems to be an unreliable connection between our (both external) data centers. Just because your provider says you have a solid gigabit connection does not mean you should believe them.

If you're reading this, you may be having the same problem.

If you are, read through all the comments and follow Mario's excellent suggestions to rule out other problems. If you are still having these same weird, intermittent issues, your steps are:

- Reboot all nodes (both datacenters), in quick succession.
- Wait 24 hours.
- Reboot all nodes (both datacenters), in quick succession.
- Wait 4 hours.
- Try again.

(I am not going to self-answer this question because the "solution" is essentially equivalent to a rain dance, and wholly unsatisfactory.)

Comment: The rebuild is probably blocked by the available ranges in `system.available_ranges` entries on each of the new nodes. To get around it, you need to remove those, either by `TRUNCATE system.available_ranges;`, or by flushing and deleting the system.available_ranges sstables. 
Before I did that, I would try to bring down the single-dc node, and validate whether data needs to be restreamed by querying the new nodes only. It's possible that most of the stored data on the first node is not live, causing the load difference.

Comment: If you could share the version, and the output of `nodetool status` from the old and a new node, it would help narrowing down other possible causes.

Comment: 3.11.4, added status output. Stupid question: wouldn't being blocked by availability give an error (and not "already available"?

Comment: Correct. It's not that the `rebuild` is failing, but rather that it is no-op. 
The rack names: 1. are they literally "Unknown", 2. you chose to change to omit the original name here, or 3. is `nodetool status` showing "Unknown" even though you configured the rack name as something else?
Trying to understand if there's an issue with the snitch. 
As for the `nodetool status` output - was it taken from the old or a new node? Did you check if the output was consistent across all nodes old and new?

Comment: All nodes show the same for `nodetool status`. Also, I specifically configured `Unknown` for rack, they're datacenter VMs, I have no idea what rack they're in :-)

Comment: That's very odd. All nodes report 100% token ownership, so replication is set correctly. All `nodetool status` output is the same, so topology/snitch are set correctly. The fact that you got "Unable to find sufficient sources" when rebuilding may mean that there's some network issue, but I'm not convinced of that.

Did you try cleaning up the  `system.available_ranges` table **on the new nodes** and retry the rebuild?

Comment: Also, I tried again and it looks data is actually streaming now. I literally changed nothing between no-op, key error and it now working. Cassandra

Comment: Going through the logs, Mario, it looks like it actually is an intermittent network issue; there's all kinds of wacky periods of version handshake issues, then nothing for hours... anyway, things seem to be working, for now, fingers crossed -- you rule.

Comment: Fun fact: rebuild went fine for the first 2 nodes, then the third node did the instant-return no-action. Restarted it, got another range error. THAT node now doesn't see the one in the other DC. Restarted THAT node, now nobody sees each other and it's all version handshake errors. I am so sick of this.

Comment: Seems like the typical nightmarish gossip issue trip :( 
The fact that there are intermittent network issues doesn't help. Gossip issues can be caused by several factors, but in most cases aimlessly rolling restarting nodes until it works fixes the problem. Out of curiosity, how did you configure the seeds in **cassandra.yaml**? This is not too important, but having at least 1 node in each datacenter (ideally 2-3) in the seed list, and having the seed list synced across all nodes may slightly help here.

Comment: Another tip to check if the nodes own the right cluster metadata is to run `nodetool gossipinfo` on each node and making sure it checks out. Alternatively, you can also run in `cqlsh` : `SELECT * FROM system.peers`. You should see every node there, except the local one, whose metadata is stored in `system.local`.